# Как указать ссылку на другой cshtml документ в asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

На этом примере: Допустим, необходимо, чтобы после нажатия на гиперссылку переходило на страницу buy.cshtml

```html
@foreach (WebApplication1.Models.Book b in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td><p>@b.Name</p></td>
        <td><p>@b.Author</p></td>
        <td><p>@b.Price</p></td>
        <td><p><a href="">Купить</a></p></td>
    </tr>
}
```

В этом файловом узле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в контроллере home есть метод Buy?

Comment: если да то так: `<a href="@Url.Action("Buy", "Home")">Купить</a>`

Comment: можно сразу `@Html.ActionLink` для генерации `<a>` целиком.

Comment: @Ruslan_K Спасибо.

Comment: @teran спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Если в контроллере home есть метод Buy, тогда

```html
<a href="@Url.Action("Buy", "Home")">Купить</a>
```

2) Можно сразу @Html.ActionLink для генерации  целиком